# Rust HashMap find_or_insert

Tags: hashmap, rust

Why does HashMap.find_or_insert(k,v) return a &mut type, and how do it get it to return a `type`?

I just started using Rust for a course, and I am using a `HashMap<int, int>` and want to get an `int` back.

```
let mut m: HashMap<int, int> = HashMap::new();
println!("{:d}", m.find_or_insert(1,2));
```

gives me an error saying that it `failed to find an implementation of trait std::fnt::Signed for &mut int`.

---

Edit1:

I am using Rust 0.9 on Windows 8.1, using msys.

My code so far

```
use std::hashmap::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let mut m: HashMap<int, int> = HashMap::new();
    println!("{:d}", *m.find_or_insert(1,2))
}
```

---

I tried this code again and it properly returns `2`

Comment: find_or_insert is no longer a method of HashMap in rust.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why does `find_or_insert` return a reference? Copying isn’t always possible/efficient.

How can you use that reference in the case of an integer? Dereference it with a `*`:

```
let mut m: HashMap<int, int> = HashMap::new();
println!("{:d}", *m.find_or_insert(1,2));
```

Comment: Your explanation of "why" makes sense, but when I use the * to dereference I get `Error: Please provide a number as argument` at runtime.  Do you know why I am not getting an int?

Comment: @zephyrthenoble: No, I don’t… are you using Rust 0.9? Is this your code exactly?

Comment: I am using Rust 0.9 on Windows 8.1.  Using your code, mine fails to compile because you don't have <int, int>.  I will edit my question to show my exact code.

Comment: @zephyrthenoble: Sorry about that! It was a side-effect of using HTML.

Comment: No problem.  I tried your code and it worked.  I'm not sure what I was doing wrong with dereferencing the pointer before.

Comment: 2019 `find_or_insert` no longer exists for the folks coming in from a search.

Comment: Tailing off of @wegry 's comment, in 2019-2020 we can write this as `m.entry(1).or_insert(2)` since `find_or_insert` has been deprecated.